# How do I change localhost:3000 to custom.domain in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, cross-domain, react-scripts

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts start",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts build",
  }
```

How do I change localhost:3000 to custom.domain in react

Comment: you want to change port right ? 3000 to other one ?

Answer (score 9):

If you are asking about purely locally serving your application you can simply append a `HOST` value before the script. Much like others have pointed out you can do with a `PORT` value.

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "HOST=custom.domain react-scripts start"
}
```

Then on your machine you will just need to ensure that you have configured your hosts files with the appropriate directive

```
127.0.0.1 custom.domain
```

Assuming you have run the start script and are serving the site you can now access it via the url `http://custom.domain:3000`

Comment: @Farid siadatzadeh: The answer of dajoto is correct. Add a line in /etc/hosts as dajoto mentioned and also change the "scripts"-"start" command alias. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Can I do it with next.js project?

Answer (score 2):

In `host` file add following lines.

Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

Linux: `/etc/hosts`

```js
127.0.0.1 mydomain.local
127.0.0.1 subdomain.mydomain.local
```

Add `HOST` in `.env` file

```js
// ..
HOST=mydomain.local
// ..
```

Run React App

`npm run start`

Visit: `mydomain.local`

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change domain you need to upload your react app to web space.
If you want to change port you need to send argument in start script.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set port=4213 && react-scripts start",
}
```

In this case port will be 4213. So site will run on http://localhost:4213

Answer (score -2):

You can change the port by doing the following change for the start command in your `package.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8050 react-scripts start",
  }
```

If you want to connect to a custom domain then hosting is the best option.

Other option is to first change the PORT no and then use some service like [ngrok](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-ngrok-test-local-site/) to expose that port.